# Conditional Expectation on the first outcome

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Assume Independent trials, resulting in one of the outcomes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 with respective probabilities $p_i$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5$ and $\sum_i p_i = 1$

Let $Z$ be the number of trials needed until the initial outcome has occurred exactly $5$ times. example: if we get $1,3,3,4,1,1,1,2,1$ then $Z=9$

**1. We want $E[Z]$**

**2. Find the expected number of trials needed until both outcome $1$ and outcome $2$ have occurred?**

For question 1, I condition on the first outcome $O_i = 1,...,5$:

$$E[Z] = E\bigg[E[Z|O_i]   \bigg] = \sum_i p_i E[Z|O_i]$$

I am thinking $E[Z|O_i]=1+ $ something. I get stuck here. Any insight?

Comment: How are you progressing? @Note

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is $1+$ **something**.   You are using the Linearity of Expectation.

$\mathsf E[Z\mid O_i]$, is the expected time until that first outcome ($i$) has its fourth subsequent occurance.

What type of distribution is the count of Bernoulli trials *until* the *next* success?

What type of distribution is the count of Bernoulli trials *until* the fourth success?

What is the expectation of this **something**?